# How to accès HTML data-attribute with Twig?

Tags: twig, custom-data-attribute, craftcms, freeform

Not sure if this is possible, but I've a link with data-attributes 'data-form-recipient' set by Json objects :

```
 <a class="callback-form" href="#location-form" id="contact-us-recipient" data-form-recipient="${myCustomLayers.properties.locationRecipient}">
```

When trying to get the data from this with JS, It looks all good and gives me the email addresses I want ->

```
var elem = document.getElementById('contact-us-recipient');
            var recipient= elem.getAttribute('data-form-recipient');
            console.log(recipient)
```

Thing is, I need to access it with Twig because this is for a Freeform dynamicNotification (Craft 3), in this context :

```
{% set form = craft.freeform.form("contactLocation", {
                                        dynamicNotification: { recipients: [
                                            recipient
                                        ], template: "locationContactTmp" }
                                    }) %}
```

Where 'recipient' must be my data-form-recipient value. Is this possible and how?
Thanks